# Rspec Ruby Basic Example Error

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run the basic starter example for using rspec found here: http://rspec.info/.

**When I type in the command prompt**

> ruby bowling_spec.rb

I get the following error

**Test**

```
# bowling_spec.rb
require 'bowling'

describe Bowling, "#score" do
  it "returns 0 for all gutter game" do
    bowling = Bowling.new
    20.times { bowling.hit(0) }
    bowling.score.should == 0
  end
end
```

**Code**

```
# bowling.rb
class Bowling
  def hit(pins)
  end

  def score
    0
  end
end
```

**Error Message**

> internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require:29:in `require': no such file to load --
>   bowling (LoadError)
>           from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
>           from bowling_spec.rb:2:in `'

Comment: Now that I think about it, this looks to be a duplicate of [Neither `ruby` and nor `irb` can load `.rb` file in current directory](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3898174/), [Why isn't current directory on my Ruby path?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4965556/), [Ruby require 'file' doesn't work but require './file' does. Why?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3795513/), [Ruby Strange Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4005013/) and probably a couple of others.

Comment: @Joerg: The answer that got accepted wouldn't be applicable to the other two questions, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a great simple example to get started with rspec. To make everything work do the following:

1. Place your bowling.rb file in
   lib/bowling.rb.
2. Place your bowling_spec.rb file in
   spec/bowling_spec.rb.
3. Run the command `rspec
   spec/bowling_spec.rb` if you are using rpsec 2.
4. Run the command `spec spec/bowling_spec.rb` if you are using rspec 1.

Also, an updated example can be found [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core).

Comment: This implementation was also a solution, and was the most complete/simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

In your bowling_spec.rb, change

```
require 'bowling'
```

to

```
require './bowling'
```

ruby 1.9 loads paths differently from ruby 1.8 and no longer adds the current directory by default

Comment: Making this change along with using rspec instead of ruby in the command prompt solved this issue.

Comment: Thanks noli, a much better introductory example here https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/docs/gettingstarted. Debugging a basic example can be frustrating when you're starting something new, you expect for rspec's official introduction to work.

Answer (score 2):

As a general hint for solving such error messages: in 99% of all cases, when a computer tells you it cannot find something, it is because that thing doesn't exist. In 99% of the rest of the cases, that thing isn't where the computer expects it to be.

The first one is obviously not the case here, since `bowling.rb` clearly *does* exist. However, your problem squarely falls into those second 99%: `require` loads a file file from Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`. But you didn't put `bowling.rb` into a directory on Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`, you simply put it in the same directory as `bowling_spec.rb`.

One obvious solution would be to add that directory to Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`. Obvious, but – in this case – wrong.

If you want to load a file relative to the position of the currently executing file, you need to use `require_relative`. This is the *right* solution in this case.

Note that, in order for the `describe` method to even *exist*, let alone work, you would also need to either add `require 'rspec'` to your spec file, or run it using the RSpec runner (i.e. `rspec bowling_spec.rb` instead of `ruby bowling_spec.rb`), but this is completely unrelated to the problem you are seeing.

Comment: In frameworks like RSpec or Rails, isn't it more likely that you forgot to supply the fairy dust? (I wish I was joking)

Answer (score 1):

First, from the example it looks like you need to run `rspec bowling_spec.rb` or `spec bowling_spec.rb` otherwise the "describe" methods used for the spec won't be loaded and you'll get some other errors.

Next, are the files both in the same directory? They need to be, with the way you have the `require` line setup. Other than that I think it looks ok.

Comment: They are in the same directory.