# rspec on NitrousIO issue

Tags: rspec, nitrousio

I've installed rspec inside my test NitrousIO box for ruby/rails. I'm trying to run a simple test but got an error:

```
action@testbox-11814:~$ rspec thetest.rb                                                                                              
/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load suc
h file -- test (LoadError)                                                                                                            
        from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'    
        from /home/action/thetest.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'                                                                          
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'              
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_
files'                                                                                                                                
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'              
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'   
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'                 
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'                       
        from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

I just have two .rb files, "test" and "thetest", this last one is the spec, sorry for the names, that quite weird but I'm just starting with NitrousIO :)

The same problem occurs when I ommit the .rb running "rspec thetest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly you should checkout some rspec [tutorial](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2007/05/14/an-introduction-to-rspec-part-i/)

here's a simple and basic example,  taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073552/rspec-ruby-basic-example-error).
From the console on NitrousIO, type:

```
gem install rspec
mkdir lib
mkdir spec
touch lib/bowling.rb
touch spec/bowling_spec.rb
```

**lib/bowling.rb**

```
require 'bowling'

describe Bowling, "#score" do
  it "returns 0 for all gutter game" do
    bowling = Bowling.new
    20.times { bowling.hit(0) }
    bowling.score.should == 0
  end
end
```

**spec/bowling_spec.rb**

```
class Bowling
  def hit(pins)
  end

  def score
    0
  end
end
```

then run:

**rspec spec/bowling_spec.rb**